# How to debug http.Agent socket queueing in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a plugin for a [Hapi.js](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi)-based REST service that is sending logging data to a log ingestion API.

When the Hapi REST service generates a large volume of logging data, the log ingestion API can't handle the volume and I see socket disconnected errors from my plugin.

I can eliminate the socket disconnect errors by configuring a `maxSockets` property on the HTTP agent, but the problem now is that it takes minutes for the sockets to be freed new data to be sent by the plugin to the log ingestion API.

For example, if I configure `maxSockets` as 50 and send 200 requests to the Hapi REST service, the first 50 log events show up in the log ingestion endpoint right away.

The next 50 events start to trickle in after 5-10 minutes ... and so on.

My question is how to do debugging to understand the life cycle of the sockets and find out why they are apparently taking so long to be freed.

Everything I've read (e.g. [node.js what happens when maxSockets are reached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807728/node-js-what-happens-when-maxsockets-are-reached) and [Node JS how to limit maximum number of sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722540/node-js-how-to-limit-maximum-number-of-sockets)) describes that `maxSockets` queues the number of concurrent sockets, but nothing in more detail about how that queueing works.

Comment: This sounds like your logging server isn't sending a proper response back and its socket has to eventually timeout before the Agent will let any more requests go.  FYI, your logging server can send a response immediately and then go about whatever it was going to do to also shorten the "in use" time for the socket that delivered the message.

Comment: FYI, you may also want to consider grouping requests so multiple messages are grouped together whenever the socket pool is busy.  This reduces the number of roundtrip requests when the system gets busy.

Comment: I've done grouping / batching of requests and that can help somewhat, but if a high enough volume of logs are generate, I still get into a queueing situation.

Also, if I just hit the logging server directly with requests from a simple Node.js application using the same request library as the Hapi plugin, I'm not seeing the same queueing issues.

Comment: So, you're saying this issue is being caused by the HAPI plugin?

Comment: It might be caused by the plugin or the overall Hapi ecosystem or something else entirely ... I'm not sure.